# Change color of Paticle(circle) when collision detected in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

// Initial Setup

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

// Canvas size

```
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;
```

//Color

```
const colors = [
    {r: 51, g: 99, b: 252}
    //{r: 77, g: 57, b: 206}, 
    // {r: 0, g: 189, b: 255}, 
];
```

// Utility Functions

```
function randomIntFromRange(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function randomColor(colors) {
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}

function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    const xDist = x2 - x1;
    const yDist = y2 - y1;

    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xDist, 2) + Math.pow(yDist, 2));
}

function rotateVelocities(velocity, theta) {
    const rotatedVelocity = {
        x: velocity.x * Math.cos(theta) - velocity.y * Math.sin(theta),
        y: velocity.x * Math.sin(theta) + velocity.y * Math.cos(theta)
    };
    return rotatedVelocity;
}
```

// Objects

```
function Particle(x, y, radius, rgb) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.velocity = {
        x: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 3,
        y: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 3
    };
    this.radius = radius;
    this.mass = 1;
    this.opacity = 0;
    this.r = rgb.r;
    this.g = rgb.g;
    this.b = rgb.b;

    this.update = particles => {
        this.draw();

        for (let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
            const otherParticle = particles[i];
            if (this.x === otherParticle.x) continue;

            if (distance(this.x, this.y, otherParticle.x, otherParticle.y) - this.radius * 2 < 0) {

                const res = {
                    x: this.velocity.x - otherParticle.velocity.x,
                    y: this.velocity.y - otherParticle.velocity.y
                };

                if (res.x * (otherParticle.x - this.x) + res.y * (otherParticle.y - this.y) >= 0) {

                    const m1 = this.mass;
                    const m2 = otherParticle.mass;
                    const theta = -Math.atan2(otherParticle.y - this.y, otherParticle.x - this.x);

                    const rotatedVelocity1 = rotateVelocities(this.velocity, theta);
                    const rotatedVelocity2 = rotateVelocities(otherParticle.velocity, theta);

                    const swapVelocity1 = { x: rotatedVelocity1.x * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + rotatedVelocity2.x * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2), y: rotatedVelocity1.y };
                    const swapVelocity2 = { x: rotatedVelocity2.x * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + rotatedVelocity1.x * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2), y: rotatedVelocity2.y };

                    const u1 = rotateVelocities(swapVelocity1, -theta);
                    const u2 = rotateVelocities(swapVelocity2, -theta);

                    this.velocity.x = u1.x;
                    this.velocity.y = u1.y;
                    otherParticle.velocity.x = u2.x;
                    otherParticle.velocity.y = u2.y;
                }
            }

            if (distance(this.x, this.y, otherParticle.x, otherParticle.y) - this.radius * 2 < 0 ) {
                this.opacity = 0.1;
            }
        }

        if (this.x + this.radius >= canvas.width || this.x - this.radius <= 0)
            this.velocity.x = -this.velocity.x;

        if (this.y + this.radius >= canvas.height || this.y - this.radius <= 0)
            this.velocity.y = -this.velocity.y;

        this.x += this.velocity.x;
        this.y += this.velocity.y;
    };

    this.draw = () => {
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        c.strokeStyle = `rgba(${this.r}, ${this.g}, ${this.b}, 1)`;
        c.stroke();
        c.fillStyle = `rgba(${this.r}, ${this.g}, ${this.b}, ${this.opacity}`;
        c.fill();
        c.closePath();
    };
}
```

// Implementation

```
let particles;

function init() {
    particles = [];
    let radius = 80

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let x = randomIntFromRange(radius, innerWidth - radius);
        let y = randomIntFromRange(radius, innerHeight - radius);

        if (particles.length >= 1) {
            for (let j = 0; j < particles.length; j++) {
                if (distance(x, y, particles[j].x, particles[j].y) - radius * 2 < 0) {
                    x = randomIntFromRange(radius, innerWidth - radius);
                    y = randomIntFromRange(radius, innerHeight - radius);

                    j = -1;
                    continue;

                }
            }
        }

        particles.push(new Particle(x, y, radius, randomColor(colors)));
    }
}
```

//I would like to initiate one circle out of all as red and whenever the red circle collide with other circle, other circle got red and at last all circle become red. but when two white circle collide it should not become red. basically one infected circle making other circle infected by touching.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sure but not able to edit question

Comment: You can always [edit] your question

Comment: i have updated my current code in answer

Comment: if (distance(this.x, this.y, otherParticle.x, otherParticle.y) - this.radius * 2 < 0 ) {
                this.opacity = 0.1;
            } this is the code which is coloring if circle touches but not able to initiate one circle color so it infect further other circle